# Running an s6 service on start-up in Artix Linux

Tags: arch-linux, docker, gentoo

I have installed *docker* on my machine, but I cannot figure out how to make the service run on startup.

```
local/docker-s6 20200907-1 (s6-galaxy)
    s6 service scripts for docker
```

On *Arch Linux* with *systemd* I would use
`systemctl enable --now docker`
What is the equivalent on *s6* if there is one?

Comment: I have no idea, but I'd probably start looking [here](https://wiki.artixlinux.org/Main/S6#Installation_of_services). That *seems* to explain how to get stuff started at boot with s6. There's also [this](https://forum.artixlinux.org/index.php/topic,1108.0.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is what the documentation says](https://wiki.artixlinux.org/Main/S6#Basic_usage)

Specifically:

> To modify an already existing bundle, you can use the
> s6-rc-bundle-update helper script. To add something to an existing
> bundle you can just execute: `s6-rc-bundle-update add default service4`.

So the answer to your specific question would be

`s6-rc-bundle-update add default docker`.